# Do I need the unofficial patches with Skyrim from ES Anthology?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I recently purchased the Elder Scrolls Anthology box set which includes Skyrim (Legendary edition) along with its 3 DLCs for PC. My question is, despite Skyrim 1.9 version, do I still need to install the Unofficial Skyrim Patch? And also, is it advisable to be patching the 3 other DLCs as well?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The unofficial patches contain fixes for bugs that the official patches never fixed, so there is still a huge benefit to installing them all. The amount of bugs fixed by the unofficial patches is huge, so I will just leave links to the whole lists below.

- [Unofficial Skyrim Patch fixes](http://www.iguanadons.net/Unofficial%20Skyrim%20Patch%20Version%20History.html)
- [Unofficial Dawnguard Patch fixes](http://www.iguanadons.net/Unofficial%20Dawnguard%20Patch%20Version%20History.html)
- [Unofficial Hearthfire Patch fixes](http://www.iguanadons.net/Unofficial%20Hearthfire%20Patch%20Version%20History.html)
- [Unofficial Dragonborn Patch fixes](http://www.iguanadons.net/Unofficial%20Dragonborn%20Patch%20Version%20History.html)
- [Unofficial High Resolution Patch fixes](http://www.iguanadons.net/Unofficial%20High%20Resolution%20Patch%20Version%20History.html) (for the free high resolution texture DLC)